# I want to get details of products returned for a particular seller on Amazon using their API's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

I was going through their documentation but didn't find any exact API which can be used to retrieve the details of those orders which has been returned for a seller. Can anyone help me know which API to be used?

I did go through their documentation but the exact API for retrieving the details of returned order didn't find.